# Generating images over ssh

Tags: ssh, images

I'm developing a tool that generates a png file. I'm doing a lot of the work over ssh, which is getting to be a pain. Every time I make a change to the code and want to test it, I use `scp` to bring the image over to my computer so I can look at it.

Is there a better way (on Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [FuseSSH FS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html):

```
sshfs hostname: mountpoint
```

you then just point your image viewer to the created image file.

on ubuntu you install it via:

`sudo apt-get install sshfs`

Answer (score 1):

You might have some level of success with [this method](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6511) which creates a tunnel and lets you look at it from a browser essentially.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple shell script to run the remote command, copy the file over, then open it in your tool of choice.